# Laravel date query not passing data from controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am wanting to make a query which includes 'to' and 'from' parameters. I'm trying to pass the 'to' and 'from' over to the controller, to be used in the query, but `Input::get('to')` returns a `NULL` value for everything I try.

View:

```
From: <input id="from" name="from" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
To: <input id="to" name="to" type="text" class="form-control input-md"><br />

@foreach($company->users as $user) 
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('SearchCredit', 
              $user->id), 'role'=>'form')) }}
    <tr>
    <td><button type="submit" value="{{ $user->id }}" 
                       class="btn btn-link">
                       {{ $user->firstname}} {{$user->surname }}</button></td>
        <td>{{ $user->credits_sum->sum }}</td>
</tr>
{{ Form::close() }}
@endforeach
```

Route:

```
Route::post('agents/admin/account/{id}', 
            array('as' => 'SearchCredit', 
            'uses' => 'AgentsController@postSearchCredit'));
```

Controller:

```
public function postSearchCredit($id)
    {

        $from   = Input::get('to');
        $to     = Input::get('from');

            $alerts = Alert::with('location')
            ->where('user_id', '=', $id)
            ->where('created_at', '>', $from)
            ->where('created_at', '<', $to)
            ->get();
            $this->layout->content = View::make('agents.admin.search', 
                                                 array('alerts' => $alerts));
        }
    }
```

I don't want the date to be repeated multiple times, so I don't want to put it within the form as that's inside a `foreachloop`.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the input tag must be between `Form::open` and `Form::close`

**Edit**
The code must me like this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('SearchCredit', $user->id), 'role'=>'form')) }}

From: <input id="from" name="from" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
To: <input id="to" name="to" type="text" class="form-control input-md"><br />

@foreach($company->users as $user) 
    <tr>
    <td><button type="submit" value="{{ $user->id }}" 
                       class="btn btn-link">
                       {{ $user->firstname}} {{$user->surname }}</button></td>
        <td>{{ $user->credits_sum->sum }}</td>
</tr>
{{ Form::close() }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I don't want the date to be repeated multiple times. The `Form::open` and `Form::close` is within a `foreachloop` that's all.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, I've tried this, but then the `user->id` can't be found because it's been taken out of the loop. The `Form::open` uses the foreachloop to populate the `user_id`.

Comment: I understand now, one possible solution is to make two hidden inputs (to and from) inside the foreach loop and then change their values with javascript so they will contain the same text as the two inputs outside the form